# What does (?1) means in regex in PHP?

Tags: php

This is my code.
I am wondering what "((?2))" meaning in PHP.
thank you for answering.

```
$p1 = '/^((\d++(\.\d+)?|\((?2)\))((\+|\/|\*|-)(\d++(\.\d+)?|(?2)))*)$/';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1):

From https://regex101.com/ :

> 2nd Alternative ((?2))
> ( matches the character ( literally (case sensitive)
> (?2) recurses the 2nd subpattern
> ) matches the character ) literally (case sensitive)